# Better ways to replace this function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe (df) composed of hourly daily pollutants readings (5). The maximum pollutant value, either for an hour or day value will be a reference to obtain the air quality index and add it as a label to the df.

[image: AQI chart]

As an example, lets say that for a certain hour/day, the maximum value among pollutants belongs to  PM10 with a value of 65ug/m3. When referencing with the chart it is determined that the air quality index is 4, since the reading it is between the range of 50-100.

Si far the way I compute the label is by the following function:

```
# IQA label function
def get_IQA_label(df):
  for index, val in df[[x for x in df.columns if x != 'date']].iterrows():
    max_column = np.argmax(val)
    max_column_val = np.max(val)

    if max_column == 0: # O_3
        if max_column_val <= 80:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 80 < max_column_val <= 120:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 120 < max_column_val <= 180:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 180 < max_column_val <= 240:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 240 < max_column_val <= 600:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == 1: # NO_2
        if max_column_val <= 40:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val <= 100:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val <= 200:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val <= 400:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val <= 1000:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == 2: # SO_2
        if max_column_val <= 100:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 100 < max_column_val <= 200:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 200 < max_column_val <= 350:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 350 < max_column_val <= 500:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 500 < max_column_val <= 1250:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == 3: # PM_10
        if max_column_val <= 20:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 20 < max_column_val <= 35:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 35 < max_column_val <= 50:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 50 < max_column_val <= 100:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 100 < max_column_val <= 1200:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == 4: # PM_2.5
        if max_column_val <= 10:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 10 < max_column_val <= 20:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 20 < max_column_val <= 25:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 25 < max_column_val <= 50:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 50 < max_column_val <= 800:
           df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5
  return df
```

When passing a df to get daily labels:

```
day_df = get_IQA_label(day_df)
day_df
```

The output is:

```
            O_3         NO_2        SO_2        PM10        PM25        CO          Label
date                            
2001-01-01  19.685217   53.789130   10.870435   20.306522   12.505127   1.055217    2.0
2001-01-02  25.496667   64.332083   10.119167   27.647917   12.505127   0.965417    2.0
2001-01-03  17.052917   69.595833   10.700833   33.777500   12.505127   0.965833    2.0
2001-01-04  18.335000   69.926666   11.472500   36.369583   12.505127   0.855000    2.0
2001-01-05  9.731667    65.272917   10.611250   32.444167   12.505127   1.174583    2.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2018-04-27  52.875000   52.125000   1.000000    15.166667   7.125000    0.362500    1.0
2018-04-28  63.208333   30.625000   1.000000    13.000000   7.791667    0.245833    1.0
2018-04-29  68.375000   29.833333   1.000000    5.458333    3.750000    0.241667    1.0
2018-04-30  60.916667   37.375000   2.708333    4.083333    3.208333    0.279167    1.0
2018-05-01  52.000000   43.000000   4.000000    6.000000    4.000000    0.300000    1.0
```

I wonder which other ways could I aim in order to obtain the labels, I find the function get_IQA_label(df) to be a chunk of code to large and I feel it could be optimize much better.

I was thinking in converting the IQA chart into a df2 and when computing the maximum value for each row in the main pollutant df readings, create some sort of function accepting as parameters the maximum value and pollutant name in order to compare it with the df2 and obtain the air quality index.

When computing the max() value I use:

```
# Getting max values from each contaminant on each row
max_value = df.max(axis=1)
max_value
```

And in order to obtain the column name from the maximum value I use:

```
# Obtaining maximum value column name for each row
label_max_colName = hour_df.eq(hour_df.max(1), axis=0).dot(hour_df.columns)
label_max_colName
```

But the above return a series and I have not been able to pass those series to a function in order to obtain the desired result.

In summary, not too sure how to compose the df2 for the AQI chart and how to implement the function.

Comment: One quick suggestion in the interest of optimization that I can give is, use `itertuples` instead of `iterrows`, it is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend the 'cut' function. This should work given the IQA chart:

```
def get_IQA_label(df):

    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

    df_2['O_3'] = pd.cut(input_df.O_3, bins=[0,80,120,180,240,600], 
                         labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
    df_2['NO_2'] = pd.cut(input_df.NO_2, bins=[0,40,100,200,400,1000], 
                          labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
    df_2['SO_2'] = pd.cut(input_df.SO_2, bins=[0,100,200,350,500,1250], 
                          labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
    df_2['PM10'] = pd.cut(input_df.PM10, bins=[0,20,35,50,100,1200], 
                          labels=[1,2,3,4,5])
    df_2['PM25'] = pd.cut(input_df.PM25, bins=[0,10,20,25,50,800], 
                          labels=[1,2,3,4,5])

    df['Label'] = temp_df.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: But this is creating a new df with the IQA for each column value and as a 'Label' the maximum reading value of the row. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right! I fixed it so it adds it straight to the df you input. Give it a shot, I'm fairly sure this is the answer you're looking for.